# Use PHP to populate chart.js with data from an SQLite Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite, chart.js

I would like to use chart.js to graph data from an SQLite database queried with PHP. I've tried several online tutorials but my graph is never populated with those and most times just disappears. I have never used PHP before and am very confused with what I am doing. Most of the tutorials I'm trying to learn from are echoing the rows from the database but I need to pass them to JavaScript to be graphed. I don't know if it will be much help but here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
        <title>Graph</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <?php
            $dir = 'sqlite:/home/pi/AQUASOLAR/SHT30/log_db/db.sht.6.db';
            $dbh = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM READING");
            foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
                //$r0 = $row[0];
                $r0 = $row[0]
            }
            $dbh = null;
        ?>
        <script>
            //from db
            var r0 = <?php echo $r0?>
            var Temp = [1,2,3]; //y axis
            var Humi = [4,5,6]; //y2 axis
            var Itn = [r0];  //x axis
            
            var graph = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var line_graph = new Chart(graph, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: Itn,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data: Temp,
                        },
                        {
                            data: Humi,
                        }
                    ],
                },
                options: { 
                    scales: { 
                            x: { 
                                ticks: { 
                                    //display: false
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone can give me some pointers that would be great, I've been having a difficult time finding tutorials for this one. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an `ajax` call?

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man do you mind elaborating on how that would work? I'm not very familiar with Ajax.

Comment: You create a `php` file where you interact with the database and return a `json` with the data that you would rapresent. Client side, you use the `ajax` call to invoke the `php` created, get the data and build the plot.

Comment: `var r0 = <?php echo $r0?>` - $r0 is an array, you can not output an array using `echo`, that will only get you the _word_ `Array`. You should be populating the appropriate data structure that corresponds to the format the graph script needs, and use `json_encode` to create a representation of it that can be used as valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`getData.php`:

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/home/pi/AQUASOLAR/SHT30/log_db/db.sht.6.db';
$dbh = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM READING");
$r0 = Array();
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
  $r0 = $row[0];
}
$dbh = null;
echo json_encode($r0);
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ..
  <body>

    <script>
      // include jquery
      $.ajax({
        url: './getData.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: (data) => {
          const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
          // Use parsed to create your chart
        },
        error: (err) => {
          alert(err);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is just an example of the logic that I use to resolve the problem. Maybe there are some sintax error

Comment: I am getting a 404 error for the php file it is in the same directory as the html file.

Comment: @frustratedscreaming Can you update your question with your MWE?

Comment: I may have not been linking the database in flask to begin with (hence the 404) here is a post with my solution outlining how I did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270450/how-do-i-link-a-csv-file-to-flask?noredirect=1#comment125979001_71270450 I may just attempt using your solution since i have data coming in from the db.